# I can't seem to delete all messages except the most recent

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I'm using the following code which you may recognise from php.net to delete all the emails in my inbox:

```
function deleteEmails($emailAddress)
{    
    // connect to gmail with your credentials
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = $emailAddress; # e.g somebody@gmail.com
    $password = '****************';


    // try to connect
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot download information: ' . imap_last_error());

    $check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($inbox);
    echo "Messages before delete: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";

    imap_delete($inbox, '1:*');

    $check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($inbox);
    echo "Messages after  delete: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";

    imap_expunge($inbox);

    $check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($inbox);
    echo "Messages after expunge: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";

    imap_close($inbox);
}
```

which helps deal with a clog in my account that happens on occasion if I let it get out of hand.  However, what I really need is for it to delete all my email except the most recent one.  I have tried to change `imap_delete($inbox, '1:*');` to `imap_delete($inbox, '2:*');` but this just caused it to not work at all.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
With advise below I tried the following:

```
imap_delete($inbox, "2:$check->Nmsgs");
```

But interestingly it deleted all but one of the 'conversations' but in gmail 'conversations' can max out at 61 emails!  I'm not sure how to get around this.  Also, the deleted ones returned after a few mins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  Gmail by default is set up using 'conversations' meaning any emails coming in with the same subject get grouped together.  This screws with everything but it can be turned off in gmail settings.  Once done I needed to make sure I was deleting all but the most recent.  using `imap_delete($inbox,2:$check->Nmsgs);` deleted all but the oldest. so the following code did it for me:

```
        $emails = ($check->Nmsgs)-1;
    imap_delete($inbox, '1:' . $emails);
```

so that I was getting the numbers but was deleting all up to the last one to come in (the most recent)

Done

Answer (score 0):

I know gmail does some interesting stuff with just tagging it differently and putting it in an All Mail folder, since there aren't actual "Folders" like on most IMAP systems.  Have you tried just giving it a range, such as

```
imap_delete($inbox,2:$check->Nmsgs);
```

If that doesn't work, you might have to just loop through marking them for deletion and then expunge after that.